# How to fix WooCommerce/Printful integration errors?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image: /wp-admin/admin.php?page=printful-dashboard&tab=status]

Hosted by Namecheap

I'll provide any details that can help to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was something in Namecheap's EasyWP plan - some stuff was disabled/not installed.
After switching to non-Managed WordPress plan those errors got fixed